# Clicking dock item jumps to wrong desktop

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, dock, desktop, ventura

I have multiple applications in full screen.
I have one empty desktop.
When I click an dock icon to jump to the corresponding full screen application.
It always jumps to the empty desktop instead. Only the second click jumps to the actual application.

Can I fix this somehow?